# duvida string/map c++

Tags: c++, string, comparação

Boa tarde! Estou respondendo uma lista de programação, a questão é bem fácil e sei a lógica de execução mas tem uma parte que não sei implementar, deixei ela em *itálico*.

Faça um programa que leia um arquivo texto qualquer e salve cada string lida em um map que relaciona a palavra com o seu tamanho. ***Não faça distinção entre maiúsculas e minúsculas***. Mostre todas as palavras e seus respectivos tamanhos ao final do programa .

Existe alguma forma de não fazer distinção entre letras maiúsculas e minúsculas em comparações de strings em c++?

Comment: Utilize a função tolower (ou toupper) em cada um dos caracteres sendo comparados. Você também pode utilizar a função strcasecmp de <strings.h>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
   std::string s{"Test string"};
   std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::tolower);
   std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Converta as strings para minusculo.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main ()
{
  int i=0;
  char str[]="Test String.\n";
  char c;
  while (str[i])
  {
    c=str[i];
    putchar (tolower(c));
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```